# Odoo 14 How to Get size of a files before downloading in Python from hyperlinks on a webiste

Tags: python, url, http-headers, odoo, odoo-14

so i try to add a file size info next to hyperlinks of my files. Files are on a server and on the website i have multiple hyperlinks with files to download.

I've found a python solution, but as i understand, it gets a size from a specified url

```
import requests
#importing the requests module
url = "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin"
#just a dummy file URL
info = requests.head(url)
#fetching the header information
print(info.headers)
#printing the details
```

How to change this, so automatically all hyperlinks get file size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: example is seen here: https://www.podatki.gov.pl/jednolity-plik-kontrolny/jpk_vat/pliki-do-pobrania/  there are file sizes displayed next to a file name